# 7zip - get name of extracted file

Tags: php, batch-file, extract, 7zip

I have a PHP script which executes a 7-zip extract command. The extracted file name is different than the zipped file's name. Is there a switch in 7-zip command line to specify the newly extracted file's name?

How can I store the newly extracted file's name in a PHP variable?

```
if (endsWith($currentFile, '.zip'))
{
    $extractCMD = '7z e uploads\\' . $currentFile;
    exec($extractCMD);
}
```

I'm thinking I have to do another `exec()` for the most recently created file, and store that. But there must be an easier way.

Comment: You could capture the exec output and look for the filenames behind `Extracting ..`. If it's a plain ZIP file you could just use [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/ZipArchive) to see what's inside.

Comment: I think you're on to something. How do I "capture" the exec output? I tried `$fileString = $exec($extractCMD);` but that doesn't contain the 'Extracting....' part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-o` to specify an output directory, but this will add a layer of depth:

```
7z x -oMyDir some_file.zip
```

For example, if `some_file` would normally output to `some_file/` it will now output to `MyDir/some_file/`.

If you just want to know the name of the top-level directory in the archive, that's a bit more tricky. You can get a list of files before extraction using the `l` command:

```
7z l some_file.zip
```

but then you have to analyze the file names to see *if* there's a top-level directory at all. There doesn't have to be.